# Not able to print in HTML Table format in mail body

Tags: awk

I have a Scenario where I am converting the CSV file to HTML file then using Sendmail I am printing the HTML tabular format data to the mail body. But the output is not coming in a proper format

**Data in .csv file is below**

```
A1,ABC,BCD
A2,DEF,AB
```

**Code used to convert the .csv to HTML file**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
print  "Content-Type: text/html"
print  "Content-Disposition: inline"
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>NAME</TH><TH>CITY</TH><TH>COURSE</TH>" 
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
' /demo/data.csv > /demo/demofolder/demofile.html
```

**Code to print the data in HTML tabular format**

```
(
echo "From: example@abc.com "
echo "To: example@abc.com "
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: Test HTML e-mail." 
echo "Content-Type: text/html" 
cat /demo/demofolder/demofile.html 
)| sendmail -t
```

But the output is coming like this below

[image]

I need the output in this format below

[image]

Comment: I ran your `awk` script and got a correct HTML table.

Comment: You need a blank line between the headers and body. Also, you don't need to put the headers in both the `bash` script and the `awk` script.

Comment: @Barmar Suggest me how to improve it ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` script is creating the table correctly. It looks like the problem may just be with the way you're embedding it into the email. There should only be one set of headers, and there needs to be a blank line between the headers and body.

You should escape the `"` in the HTML attribute, since double quotes are the awk string delimiters.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { print "<HTML><TABLE border=\"1\"><TH>NAME</TH><TH>CITY</TH><TH>COURSE</TH>" 
}
{
    printf "<TR>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
    print "</TR>"
}
END { print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>" }' /demo/data.csv > /demo/demofolder/demofile.html

(
echo "From: example@abc.com "
echo "To: example@abc.com "
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: Test HTML e-mail." 
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "" 
cat /demo/demofolder/demofile.html 
)| sendmail -t
```

Comment: => Thanks for the Code bro please edit <TH>CITY</TH ...its incorrect syntax .. overall the code is perfect